# How do I change the numbering in inner \item?

Tags: labels, enumitem, ref

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\bf Matter \arabic{enumi}.}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\bf Matter \arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.}
\begin{document}

There are \ref{1-item} main matters in total.

\begin{enumerate}
\item bla1
\item bla2
\item This matter consists of \ref{2-item} submatter.
\begin{enumerate}
\item bla3
\item bla4\label{2-item}
\end{enumerate}
\item bla4 \label{1-item}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

`\ref{2-item} = 3b` but `\ref{2-item}` should be `2`. How can we change this?

Comment: Why are you changing `labelenumi` etc. explicitly when `enumitem` is applied? And `\bf` is totally deprecated

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, I learned good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changing `\labelenumi` etc. does influence the way how the reference value is stored.

With `enumitem` package it should not be necessary to modify `\labelenumi` etc. but change the list settings with `\setlist`.

`label*=...` appends the parent list level label to the current item label, and `ref=` changes the reference format.

Please note that `\ref` does not provide an expandable number here in this context, just in case some `\ifnum` etc. is wanted in a more elaborate document.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate]{leftmargin=*}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label={\bfseries Matter \arabic*.},ref=\arabic*}}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label*={\bfseries\arabic*},ref={\arabic*}}
\begin{document}

There are \ref{1-item} main matters in total.

\begin{enumerate}
\item bla1
\item bla2
\item This matter consists of \ref{2-item} submatter.
\begin{enumerate}
\item bla3
\item bla4\label{2-item}
\end{enumerate}
\item bla4 \label{1-item}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. With the current setup, the "Matter" text labels protrude into the left-hand margin. If that's not desired, one should add the option `leftmargin=*` to the `\setlist[enumerate,1]{...}` directive.

Comment: In fairness, it should be noted that the protrusion-into-the-lefthand-margin issue issue is already present in the OP's own code. Maybe, just maybe, that's actually what the OP wants...

Comment: @Mico: We just don't know. If the protrusion is wanted, the `leftmargin=*` statement can be easily removed

Answer (score 3):

Just in case the document still needs to use a "basic" enumeration list somewhere, it's probably a good idea to use the machinery of the `enumitem` package to define a new enumerate-like list -- called `matter` in the example below -- which (a) prefixes the label "Matter" to the enumerated item(s) and (b) typesets both the "Matter" label and the number in bold. The following example shows how this may be done, for up to 3 levels of enumeration.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{matter}{enumerate}{3}  % create a new enumerated list
\setlist[matter,1]{label={\bfseries Matter \arabic*.},
                   ref=\arabic*,
                   leftmargin=*}
\setlist[matter,2]{label={\bfseries Matter \thematteri.\arabic{matterii}.}, 
                   ref=\arabic*}
\setlist[matter,3]{label={\bfseries Matter \thematteri.\thematterii.\arabic{matteriii}.},
                   ref=\arabic*}

\begin{document}
\noindent
There are \ref{1-item} main matters in total.

\begin{matter}
\item bla1
\item bla2
\item bla3 -- This matter features \ref{2-item} submatters.
   \begin{matter}
   \item bla31
   \item bla32\label{2-item}
      \begin{matter}
      \item bla321
      \item bla322
      \end{matter}
   \end{matter}
\item bla4 \label{1-item}
\end{matter}

\end{document}
```