# Referencing an item using labelenumi

Tags: cross-referencing, chapters, enumerate

I am writing a book in LaTeX in which I label problems m.n for Chapter m, problem n (for example, problem 6.10 is the 10th problem in Chapter 6).  I am using the declaration

```
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\arabic{enumi}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\thechapter.\theenumi}
```

and this correctly prints problem labels in the enumerate environment where the problems are listed.  However, when I refer to a problem elsewhere, it only prints the problem number (e.g., "see Problem 6.10" is written "see Problem 10").  Is there a global fix for this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. See my answer from today, which is for the same problem, basically: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403860/how-do-i-change-the-numbering-in-inner-item/403861#403861

Answer (score 2):

As Christian suggests, using the [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package is probably the best approach. I would go one step further than the answer he refers to and define a new `problems` environment for your problems. To do what you want using `enumitem` is as simple as:

```
\newlist{problems}{enumerate}{1}% or 2 or 3 if you want to nest
\setlist[problems]{label=\thechapter.\arabic*, 
                   ref=Problem \thechapter.\arabic*
}
```

Here I am assuming that you want `\ref{...}` to print something like `Problem 1.2`. If you just want it to print `1.2` then omit the `ref=...`. For more details consult the very readable `enumitem` manual.

In fact, as shown below, I would also have the `problems` environment automatically add a heading for the problems, which you can do using the `before=` option from. `enumitem`. Below I have used `\section{...}` but perhaps `\section*{...}` or `\subsection{...}` etc would work better for you.

Here a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{problems}{enumerate}{1}% or 2 or 3 if you want to nest
\setlist[problems]{label=\thechapter.\arabic*,
                   ref=Problem \thechapter.\arabic*,
                   before={\section{Problems for Chapter \thechapter}}
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}

\begin{problems}
  \item Is the Riemann hypothesis true? \label{Riemann}
  \item Find the first counter-example to the twin primes conjecture
  \label{twins}
\end{problems}

Actually, \ref{Riemann} and \ref{twins} are quite hard, so allow at
least an extra week.
\end{document}
```

For completeness, this produces:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Referencing counters uses `\the<cntr>` as it's reference content. So, instead, you should redefine `\theenumi` to fully contain your representation (as it will be set and therefore referenced):

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\newenvironment{questions}
  {\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\thechapter.\arabic{enumi}}%
   \begin{enumerate}}
  {\end{enumerate}}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{9}% Just for this example

\chapter{Questions}

See questions \ref{q:first}--\ref{q:last}.

\begin{questions}
  \item \label{q:first}
  First question

  \item
  Second question

  \item
  Third question

  \item \label{q:last}
  Last question
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

The above example redefines `\theenumi` as part of a new `questions` environment. This allows you to localise the change of definition without it affecting other `enumerate` environments (if they're used).